# is there a way to convert rows into cols in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to make the months as columns with avg price for each currency below its month. does any one know how I can pivot this?

```
cd_firstYear
      Currency month avgprice
1 binance-coin     4   4.3500
2      bitcoin     4 138.5817
3 bitcoin-cash     4 138.5817
```

Comment: there is a function called pivot_long on the dplyr package of the tidyverse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach with `pivot_wider` from `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_wider(cd_firstYear, values_from = "avgprice", names_from = "month")
## A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Currency        `4`
#  <fct>          <dbl>
#1 binance-coin    4.35
#2 bitcoin       139.  
#3 bitcoin-cash  139.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use function `pivot_wider` from package `tidyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

cd_firstYear %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = Currency,
    names_from = month,
    values_from = avgprice
  )
## A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Currency        `4`
#  <chr>         <dbl>
#1 binance-coin   4.35
#2 bitcoin      139.  
#3 bitcoin-cash 139.
```

**Data**

```
cd_firstYear <- read.table(text = "
      Currency month avgprice
1 binance-coin     4   4.3500
2      bitcoin     4 138.5817
3 bitcoin-cash     4 138.5817
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: dont know why i keep getting this error..Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Columns `12`, `12`, `12`, `12`, `12`, etc. don't exist.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: @AdetyaAggarwal Try putting the column names `month` and `avgprice` between quotes.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), Currency ~ month)
#      Currency        4
#1: binance-coin   4.3500
#2:      bitcoin 138.5817
#3: bitcoin-cash 138.5817
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Currency = c("binance-coin", "bitcoin", "bitcoin-cash"
), month = c(4L, 4L, 4L), avgprice = c(4.35, 138.5817, 138.5817
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```